# Touchpad not working after connecting hdmi cable

Tags: xorg, touchpad

I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 2 weeks back on my new laptop along side Windows 8. 1. And it was working fine. But yesterday after I connected Ubuntu with my TV using the HDMI cable, the cursor/ pointer stopped working. The pointer is not visible and my touchpad is not working.

I connected the hdmi cable with youtube in Firefox. But only the wallpaper was visible on the TV. Also the right click menu, alt tab window, etc was also visible. But the side menu and the Firefox window was not visible. The pointer was visible on the tv and the touchpad was working, I was able to move the pointer.

After I removed the HDMI cable, my cursor/pointer disappeared and my touchpad is not responding! ! I tried to restart many times, but still no luck. Its still not visible in the desktop. The pointer is visible in the login screen, but is not responding to the touchpad.

I tried to login to my KDE session, there too the pointer is visible but is not responding to the touchpad. It is not moving.

Comment: What manufacturer and model is your laptop?

Comment: what's the output of `xinput`?

Comment: My laptop is Toshiba satellite series - S50 - A.

Comment: The output of xinput is  :                                    Virtual Core pointer  -----       id=2 [master pointer     (3) ]
  -> Virtual core XTEST pointer      id=4 [slave pointer  (2) ]
  -> SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad      id=11 [slave pointer (2) ]

Virtual core keyboard       id=3 [master keyboard (2) ]

Comment: I tried to open ubuntu using the bootable usb linux.. but in that too the cursor is not visible !!

Answer (score 1):

By mistake I had pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, which enables and disables the touchpad.

Now I pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> again and now my touchpad is working as before.